# How to integrate PHP and Tomcat 7.0 together

Tags: php, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to combine PHP and JSP in my Tomcat 7.0 Server.  I have tried many tutorials, but none of them seem to work.  Can any of you give me a step-by-step way to do this, or a tutorial that does this?

Thank You in advanced

Comment: Have a look at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html).  Might be able to learn a bit from their setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to ask the question, then **it is not what you want to do**. Combining Tomcat and PHP is **rare**, advanced, highly specific and **not usually done**.

**If and only if** you are sure you need this combination - just download the Quercus war from [here](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and put in into tomcat/webapps directory. Tomcat should extract and deploy Quercus and any php file put into the extracted directory will work. Then you can ask any specific questions concerning Java-PHP integration.

Again: probably you are misguided and need something else altogether (perhaps Apache HTTP and PHP?...).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go down this road awhile back. You want to have 1 web server, but be able to have both php and java projects hosted on it.

Not a good idea as fdreger mentioned already... it is going to be a lot simpler to have an apache install, a separate tomcat install, and setup your  DNS records to point domains at the appropriate server / ports as necessary.